# How to use object from main method in another method

Tags: java, class, methods, program-entry-point

I'm trying to use `RandomGrid rGrid` in the `compareGrids` method of my project, however I can't seem to figure out how to do so. I origionally had the `RandomGrid` constructor outside the main method, but I got a stack overflow error whenever I tried to run it. I have another class very similar to this one with a `ButtonGrid` constructor outside of the main method and it works fine. Thanks for any help!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ButtonGrid(WIDTH, LENGTH);
    RandomGrid rGrid = new RandomGrid(WIDTH, LENGTH);

}
public int compareGrids() {
    String[] args = {};
    ButtonGrid.main(args);

    int numCorrect = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++) {
         if (grid[i][j].getBackground() == ButtonGrid.main(rGrid).grid[i][j].getBackground()) {
                numCorrect++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(numCorrect);
    return numCorrect;
}
```

Comment: Pass your `rGrid ` to `compareGrids` or make it static

Comment: What do you mean by pass it?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:
Make compareGrids() static and add arguments

```
public static int compareGrids(Grid grid1, Grid grid2) {
 ...
}
```

This is an entry level question, You may want to consult a simple java tutorial to understand basic class elements and modifiers

Answer (score 0):

To use rGrid in compareGrids it has to be class level variable .
Declare 
RandomGrid rGrid = new RandomGrid(WIDTH, LENGTH); 
outside main.
It should solve your issue.
Presently scope of rgrid ends as soon as main method finishes

Please paste stack overflow error that you mentioned